# How jQuery Snap To Elements Works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was puzzled when I saw jQuery "Snap to element". Does anyone know how can I implement it without jQuery, with just raw javascript.

Thanks

Comment: You can do **anything** jQuery (or any plugins) can do using just vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: I know it can be done using just javascript but whats the core logic behind the functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've built a drag and drop implementation without jQuery UI to have it snap to another element you need to now do the following:

- Determine the position and dimensions of the dragging object and other objects to which you want the element to be able to snap to
- While an object is being dragged you need to determine if the object being dragged is within your arbitrary threshold distance of an object it can snap to at that point you bump the dragged elements left/top to match the left/top/bottom/right position of the "snappable" element

Comment: but in my case, the draggable element can be snapped to any element whose dimensions and position is not known to me.

Comment: I might write up a loop that checks for all the nodes and check if my element is bumping any of them, but this would be very inefficient. OR is jQuery doing the same thing?

Comment: jQuery is checking it's location whenever the drag event occurs on the draggable element.